# Using an Object with ream codable

Tags: ios, swift, realm, codable

I have an application where I tried using `UserDefaults` to save a **Codable model** locally but the problem is that `UserDefault` does not store all the `values` of the **Model** and assigns `nil` to some of them and at times the proper `value` is assigned. So I decided to try an alternative which is **realm** and I am able to modify my **model** to work with **realm** but I have an issue not which is in the *process* of *decoding an* **Object** in an **Object** *using realm*. I was able to make it work when dealing with an `Array` **object** with `List` but non `array` **Objects** simply **failed** to map to **JSON**

below is a sample array that I am dealing with

```
{
    "id": 732,
    "name": "Vendor Name",
    "logo": ".../thumb/missing.png",
    "kitchens":
      {
        "id": 36,
        "name": "Sandwiches"
      }
  }
```

model class

```
class VendorsList : Object, Decodable {
    @objc dynamic var id : Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var name : String?
    @objc dynamic var logo : String?
    // Create your Realm List.
    var kitchensList = List<VendorKitchens>()

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case logo
        // Set JSON Object Key
        case kitchensList = "kitchens"

    }

    public required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.init()
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.logo = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .logo)
        // Map your JSON Array response
        let kitchens = try container.decodeIfPresent([VendorKitchens].self, forKey: .kitchensList) ?? [VendorKitchens()]
        kitchensList.append(objectsIn: kitchens)

    }

}


class VendorKitchens : Object, Decodable {
    @objc dynamic var id : Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var name : String?

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
    }
}
```

this `returns` an **error**

> Failed to map data to JSON

Comment: Is this your custom error message or the actual thrown error?

Comment: it is a codable error `Failed to map data to JSON`

Comment: That's not a built-in error `JSONDecoder` would throw. You should [edit] your question with the code you use for decoding along with the actual error message. Unrelated to your issue, but you want to use `[VendorKitchens]()` as the default value in the line `let kitchens = ...`, because that initializes an empty `Array`, while your current code of `[VendorKitchens()]` creates an array with a single element.

Comment: In your JSON, the value associated with the key `kitchens` is not an array. It is a single object.

Comment: `...map data to JSON` seems to be an **En**codable error which makes no sense.

Comment: yes @vadian you are correct

Comment: @Sweeper you are correct if I make it a regular var, I get the same error `Failed to map data to JSON`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, try this.

```
class VendorsList : Object, Decodable {
    @objc dynamic var id : Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var name : String?
    @objc dynamic var logo : String?
    @objc dynamic var kitchens: VendorKitchens? = nil

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case logo
        case kitchens = "kitchens"

    }

    public required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.init()
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.logo = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .logo)
        kitchens = try container.decodeIfPresent(VendorKitchens.self, forKey: .kitchensList)

    }

}


class VendorKitchens : Object, Decodable {
    @objc dynamic var id : Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var name : String?

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
    }
}
```